# Simple PHP Form Templating

Tags: php, html, forms, templating

You have a PHP form with the following field in it:

(code block 1)

```
City: <input type="text" name="city"><br>
```

The form's `action attribute` is set to `itself`. When `submitted` to the server, the page validates the field, and if it's invalid it returns the same page with:

1. An error message
2. A red border around the form text input box
3. The value the user originally inputted inside the form input text box

I could use an `if then else` construct and return `code block 2` if invalid.

(code block 2)

```
<?php echo "The form field with red border has an invalid entry"; ?>
City: <input type="text" name="city"
style="border-color:red" value="<?php echo $record->city ?>"><br>
```

My question is, if you were to add some templating to `code block 1` so that you wouldn't need `code block 2`, how would you do it?

Please narrow your *answer set* to:

1. pure PHP answers (without any external templating  libraries or PHP frameworks).
2. suitable for someone for whom PHP is the only server side scripting they know (and they are relatively inexperienced with it).

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Okay, am narrowing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an if/else you could create an $has_error associated array and integrate that directly into your original form like so:

```
City: 
<input type="text" name="city" class="<?= $has_error['city']['class'] ?>" value="<?= $record->city ?>">
<span><?= $has_error['city']['message'] ?></span>
<br>
```

and structure your validation errors like so:

```
$has_error = [
  'city' = [
    'class' => '',
    'message'=> ''
  ]
]
```

Then apply an error class and message on the validation side (where ever you submit your form). So when the `city` input field doesn't pass validation your `$has_error` array would look like this:

```
$has_error = [
  'city' = [
    'class' => 'error',
    'message'=> 'This field has an error'
  ]
]
```

Your error class would look something like this:

```
.error{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. By `URL variables` do you mean a `GET` type request? Also, any advantage over using `$_SESSION['xyz']` variables?

Comment: $_SESSION will work well for this situation.

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer. Why are people in the community so vicious and mean-spirited?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, an insightful comment would have been helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to tackle this would be to add the formatting from `code block 2` to your CSS file, and then use PHP to add the class to your input.

CSS:

```
.errorField {
    border-color: red;
}
```

HTML/inline PHP:

```
City: <input type="text" <?php echo errorCity ? 'class="errorField"' : '' ?> name="city" value="<?php echo $record->city ?>"><br>
```

And have your validation PHP set `errorCity` to `true` if the input is invalid.

What the inline PHP is doing is checking the value of bool `errorCity` and echoing `class="errorField"` if it's true, or nothing if it's false.

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer. Why are people in the community so vicious and mean-spirited?

Comment: I've no idea. It hurts my heart :( Reputation is hard to earn around here, and I got excited when I saw your upvote lol.